# How to pick a parent node then iterate over other node (with different label) and find some information and do it repeatedly for each parent node

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

So, I am working with Neo4J and I have a problem where I have 2 different nodes (one called :Road and other called :Landmark) both of them have a property called coordinate that is the location of this point in wsg-84 system (created using spatial datatype in neo4j basically i.e. `point()` ). I need to create a relation between a :Road and a :Landmark where the distance is the minimum between them (geodesic distance).

I am using spatial function like `point.distance(r.coordinate,l.coordinate)` to find the distance between them but I am not able to understand **how to find the closest distance from a :Landmark to a :Road and then create a relation between them**. It is possible to for a :Road to have multiple :Landmark related to it but each :Landmark should have only one :Road related to it. Can somebody help me write a cypher query for this.

```
MATCH (l:Landmark)
OPTIONAL MATCH (r:Road)
with p,apoc.coll.sortMaps(collect({road:r,dist:point.distance(l.coordinate ,r.coordinate)}),"dist") as minDist
CREATE (l) -[:relatesTo]->(head(minDist).road)
```

I tried things like this but even when I return the values l and head of minDist it is it is the minDist part is same for all entries. This does not work it maps all :Landmarks to one :Road. Please help

Comment: Your `WITH` clause references a non-existent `p` variable. Did you mean `l` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apoc.agg.minItems](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.agg/apoc.agg.minItems/) function to simplify the logic:

```
MATCH (l:Landmark), (r:Road)
WITH l, apoc.agg.minItems(r, point.distance(l.coordinate ,r.coordinate), 1).items[0] AS nearestRoad
CREATE (l)-[:relatesTo]->(nearestRoad)
```

If you will still get the same results, then it is probably the case that there is actually one road that is the closes to all your landmarks.